# How to save an EXT JS element's attribute value in Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, extjs, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework and I would like to save the Value/TagValue of an extJS element to a variable. You can find the HTML of the element below.

I already tried to save the value with the builtin methods, following:

> ${var} | Get Text | //input[@data-qtip='Kezdő időszak']

```
Return: empty string
```

> ${var} | Get Element attribute | //input[@data-qtip='Kezdő időszak'] | Value

```
Return: None
```

> ${var} | Get Element attribute | //input[@data-qtip='Kezdő időszak'] | TagValue

```
Return: None
```

I know that 'Value' and 'TagValue' attribute hold the value needed (checked it with Ranorex Spy), but could not access it with RFW builtin methods. The problem very well may be, that these attributes are not generated in the HTML by the extJS framework...

Is there another solution to save the value?

**ExtJS WebElement:**

```html
<input id="smartcombo-4012-inputEl" data-ref="inputEl" type="text" data-qtip="Kezdő időszak" size="1" name="startPeriodId" role="combobox" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-text-default " autocomplete="off" data-componentid="smartcombo-4012" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by executing a javascript. Get ext component by `Ext.getCmp` with componentid and do `getValue` method on component.

Something like:

```
${combovalue}=      Execute Javascript       return Ext.getCmp("smartcombo-4012").getValue();
```

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot to reply. I searched for this issue again and accidently found my own question :)
The method you suggested works fine, thank you vey much! :)
One problem with it though: The componentid is not static, it changes when you generate the code in the framework if i'm not mistaken. Thus one should not use it for automation.
The workaround is to save the 'data-componentid' attribute of the node and use that in the javascript. Works like a charm. :)
Thank you!